# Python Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, error-handling

Can I catch in any way the current year in the Django template language? I need to create a link for the current year and I don't want to pass it by hand. And sending it via the view throws me an error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'blog_archive_year' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'year': ''}' not found.
```

Here is the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$',
        view='post_archive_year',
        name='blog_archive_year'
```

view

```
def post_archive_year(request, year, **kwargs):
    #now = datetime.datetime.now()
    #current_year = now.year
    return date_based.archive_year(
        request,
        #year=current_year,
        year=year,
        date_field='publish',
        queryset=Post.objects.published(),
        make_object_list=True,
        **kwargs
    )
post_archive_year.__doc__ = date_based.archive_year.__doc__
```

and this is the dummy template: <

```
<a href="{% url blog_archive_year year=2011(I'd like to send him year here) %}">Articols archive</a>
```

Please help:)

Answer (score 2):

First you should define the year pattern in the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'post_archive_year', name='blog_archive_year')
```

To print the current year in a template use:

```
{% now Y %}
```

Comment: Can I save the content of {% now "Y" %} in a variable somehow? it keeps prompting errors if I pass it like: url blog_archive_year year={% now "Y" %} or like url blog_archive_year year=now "Y".

Comment: I don't think it's possible to pass 'now' to the url tag. I suggest you to add the year to your template context in your view.